# How do I get a Docker container configuration for a single application?

Tags: docker, containers

I'm trying to dissect a Docker app that was built by someone else, and since this is my first time touching Docker, I'm struggling to understand the concepts so please forgive me if I have the wrong semantics.

So the commands being run to start and kick off the Docker app were just the following:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run app
```

Looking at documentation for `docker-compose`, since that command supposedly refers to a multi-container app, I looked at the `docker-compose.yml`, which has just the following contents:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    entrypoint: ["pipenv", "run", "python", "main.py"]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: proj_dir/Dockerfile
```

I'm trying to get the configuration of the Docker container to replicate the container and environment on my local machine. So I'm a little confused where to get all the settings, at least memory, of the container.  If it helps, this is being run on a GCP project Cloudshell.

Comment: As per this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler allows.

Comment: I recommend starting off by learning how to build a container image first. Then you will learn that containers are built from layers. If you have the Dockerfile for the container you have the steps from the base image. Usually the base image was built from a Dockerfile, etc. To see the layers use the Docker command `docker history <image>`. This link will give your more information about reverse engineering an image: https://dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-docker-images-into-dockerfiles

Comment: That `docker-compose.yml` file (and the matching `proj_dir/Dockerfile`) is the configuration you need to replicate the container on your local machine; you should be able to check out the same source tree on your local system and run `docker-compose up --build` there.